# How to write operand with 2 columns in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have problem writing a query which contains 2 fields:

```
SELECT product_id 
FROM product 
WHERE product_id NOT IN (SELECT product_one, product_two 
                         FROM product_group);
```

The problem in subquery is that I'm  selecting 2 fields. But I really can't understand how to fish out only those ids which are not members of other table.
I tried `union` but it is not working as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below query:

```
SELECT product_id FROM probuct WHERE product_id NOT IN 
(select product_one from product_group
UNION
select  product_two from product_group
);
```

OR

```
SELECT product_id FROM probuct WHERE product_id NOT IN 
(select product_one from product_group
) 
AND product_id NOT IN
(select  product_two from product_group
);
```

Comment: let me try. I will try it now

Comment: May I ask why the `union` in subquery solved the problem? it seems line we are still selecting 2 columns right?

Comment: yes union combines both output into one column and then compare with product_id

Comment: you can not compare one column with two, just think about it

Comment: yes of course. but I thought the return of subquery is a sort of and array. Apparently I was wrong :)

Comment: it is an array but contains only one column not more than that